Tailwind/Nuxt issue - inline space between elements is missing
When using tailwind v3.4.3 on tailwind playground space is added b/w span elements
<div>
  <p>
    <span class="bg-slate-800">TEST</span>
    <span class="bg-orange-600">TEST 2</span>
    <span class="bg-yellow-500">TEST 3</span>
  </p>
</div>

Copy Paste the above code on play.tailwindcss.com
You can see the extra space added b/w span elements.

When I try to do similar thing in Nuxt 3 with tailwind installation, space between span elements is missing.

I have already setup edit with nuxt and tailwind configuration, editor link
I have also installed tailwind using nuxt modules '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', but still the issue persists.
I am currently migrating my project from nuxt 2 to nuxt 3, nuxt 2 project show similar behaviour as shown by tailwindcss playground, but on nuxt 3 its breaking.
Solving this space issue would be a great help to the project.

Does this answer your question? How to remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?

More of the way on how your write your code and even the bundler than anything else.

By default, Vue compiles SFCs with whitespace condensed. To change this behavior, edit nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vue: {
    compilerOptions: {
      whitespace: 'preserve'
    }
  }
})

FYI, when not using Nuxt, the required config change is slightly different in vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          whitespace: 'preserve'
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})

